# Store values in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I created a SP as "SP_SELECT"

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_SELECT @userid varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT Dept_Id from Master where User_Id=@userid
END
GO
```

Now the task is I have to store the **Result (i.e) Dept_Id** in a variable named as **"dept"** in the same stored procedure itself. Help me with the query.

Comment: A simple google search would solve this. This sounds like we are answering someone's homework question.

Comment: Try to avoid using `sp_` as a prefix for stored procedure names. It's only meant to be used by Microsoft for their System Procedures. Bad things can (and will!) happen if there's a Microsoft procedure of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_SELECT @userid varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @deptid int;

      SET @deptid = SELECT Dept_Id from Master where User_Id=@userid
END
RETURN @deptid
GO
```

You could also pass @deptid as an output parameter in sql.

But this var will only exist each time the stored proc is run on the calling function or code you will still need to store the value.

i.e.

```
Declare @masterdeptid int;
SET @masterdeptid = EXEC SP_Select '123';
```

I ain't test the sql but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
set  @dept= (select Dept_Id from Master where User_Id=@userid)
```

and if you want return this value to front end , write below code

```
set  @dept= (select Dept_Id from Master where User_Id=@userid)
select @dept
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful to you

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_SELECT @userid varchar(50), @Dept int output
AS
BEGIN
      SELECT @Dept = Dept_Id from Master where User_Id=@userid
END
```

above code can be executed as

```
Declare @Dept int;
EXEC USP_Select '123',@Dept output
Print @Dept
```